# Flash Game Error #1063

Tags: flash, actionscript

I've been coding the beginnings of a pretty basic game and I have hit a wall. When I compile my code, the game runs but spits out a run-time error:

> ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on block(). Expected 2, got 0.
> at flash.display:: Sprite/constructChildren()
> at flash display::Sprite()
> at flash.display::MovieClip()
> at AvoiderGame().

Here is my document class titled `AvoiderGame`:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;

    public class AvoiderGame extends MovieClip
    {

        public var avatar1:avatar;
        public var gameTimer:Timer;
        public var army:Array;

        public function AvoiderGame()
        {
            army=new Array();
            var newblock= new block(100,-15);
            army.push(newblock);
            addChild(newblock);

            avatar1=new avatar();
            addChild (avatar1);
            avatar1.x=mouseX;
            avatar1.y=mouseY;

            gameTimer=new Timer(25);
            gameTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTick);
            gameTimer.start();

        }


        public function onTick(timerEvent:TimerEvent):void
        {
            if ( Math.random() < 0.1 )
            {
                var randomX:Number = Math.random() * 400;
                var newblock:block = new block( randomX, -15 );

                army.push( newblock );
                addChild( newblock );
            }

            avatar1.x = mouseX;
            avatar1.y = mouseY;

            for each (var block1:block in army)
            {
                block1.moveDownaBit();

                if (avatar1.hitTestObject(block1))
                {
                    gameTimer.stop();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally here is my `block` class which seems to have the constructor function causing the error.

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class block extends MovieClip
    {
        public var block1:block;

        public function block(startX:Number, startY:Number)
        {
            x=startX;
            y=startY;
        }

        public function moveDownaBit():void
        {
            y=y+3;
        }
    }
}
```

All I'm trying to get to work is a series of enemies spawning randomly on the stage and falling down without the avatar icon hitting it. I would appreciate any help I can receive greatly.

Comment: Hi, I've updated your question and the answer that @DavidMear provided to use the word `block`.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like you've got an instance of `block` on the stage, so Flash is creating it without passing `startX` and `startY`. You can either remove any pre-placed blocks, or just add default values to the constructor:

```
public function block(startX:Number = 0,startY:Number = 0)
{
    x = startX;
    y = startY;
}
```

Comment: dang knew it was some elementary I wasn't catching.  Thanks at ton!!